# Was ever observed a black hole - neutron star merger?

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves, neutron-stars, ligo

I remember that a few months ago the news of a possible a black hole-neutron star merger detected with LIGO/VIRGO was diffused.

Was this discovery confirmed?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gravitational_wave_observations. In the table in section "Observation candidates from O3/2019" the column "NS/BH" gives the probability that one component was a neutron star and the other was a black hole. For example S190814bv is assessed as a 99.8% probability of being a NS/BH merger.

Answer (score 0):

During O1 and O2 run there was a detection with a low probability of a NS-BH merger, but physicists are sure it was a BBH merger.

However, lets be optimititc because LIGO/Virgo have measured 5 NS-BH mergers in the O3 run. I have been told that LIGO is going to do in April a press conference talking about all these results. Lets be patient until then.

Even more, KAGRA, the japanese observatory for gravitacional waves is about to start measuring too in late February.

Comment: I am interested in an update here - what was the outcome of that press conference?