# Are there any black hole neutron star binary?

Tags: black-holes, astronomy, neutron-stars, binary-stars

Has a black hole-neutron star binary aver been observed?

I mean observed in any way: gravitationally, through eclipse, or any other means.

**EDIT** Thanks to the comment to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/530474/46926) question, we know that some system are known from GW observation.

Are these observations the only ones?

Comment: Detecting gravitational waves with LIGO is the only current method I'm aware of. You might want to try posting your question on astronomy stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from the website of the [BlackHoleCam](https://blackholecam.org/research/pulsars/) European Research Council Project (as of 17/2/2020):

> Although pulsar-BH systems can provide unique benchmarks of theories of gravity, they are expected to be very rare and to date not a single pulsar-BH system has yet been found.

In principle, a pulsar-BH system could be used to confirm the black hole nature of the companion and measure the BH mass and spin, by analysing the precise timing of the (radio) pulses from the pulsar.

If the neutron star is not a pulsar, then there is little to give these binaries away, except when they merge.

There are a number of [candidate systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gravitational_wave_observations#Observation_candidates_from_O3/2019) that have been suggested as the source of detected gravitational wave signals from merging compact objects, but [no optical counterpart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gravitational_wave_observations#Observation_candidates_from_O3/2019) has yet been reported that might offer some confirming evidence.